# How can I parse CSV line by line and parse out multiple keywords and their data?

Tags: c#, csv

I have a CSV file that contains data like the following below (but lots more):

```
Date             dd/mm/yyyy
ExpirationDate   dd/mm/yyyy
Lot              6760786776 
Serial           34659FSFHS45

DataType       Unknown   Count          
A(Loc1, Loc2)  Unknown   Variable1 Variable2 Variable3 
B(Loc3, Loc4)  Unknown   Variable4 Variable5 Variable6

DataType       Unknown   Apple         
A(Loc1, Loc2)  Unknown   Variable1 Variable2 Variable3 
B(Loc3, Loc4)  Unknown   Variable4 Variable5 Variable6
```

etc....

Currently, I have something like this:

```
 public void DeserialCSVStream(string filePath)
    {
        using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(filePath))

        {
            string currentline;
            while ((currentline = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
            {
                if (currentline.IndexOf("Date", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >=0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(currentline);
                }
                else if (currentline.IndexOf("Lot", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(currentline);
                }
                else if (currentline.IndexOf("Serial", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(currentline);
                }
                else if (currentline.IndexOf("Count", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) >= 0)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine(currentline);
                }
            }

        }

    }
```

Which is okay but gives me a few problems:

-If I look for a string of "Date", it gives me not only Date but Expiration Date but I only want to parse out the Date. If I use StartsWith, it gives me null.

-Also, the above only lets me grab the columns data next to the field. E.g. Count only returns DataType and Unknown but I want to grab the whole "table" under count and not just that line where Count is on. How do I do that?

Comment: That does not look like a CSV file, but rather some sort of custom text format.

Comment: @EricJ, Sorry about the format. I fixed it a little more to look like a CSV. I was trying to illustrate an excerpt from the CSV file I have. The CSV file I have is huge, so I just took some data from it.

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a text file with a custom format, rather than a CSV (Comma Separated Value) file.

You can modify your code slightly to fix the specific problem you address by using StartsWith rather than IndexOf

```
if (currentline.StartsWith("Date:", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase))
```

If there is a possibility of any leading space you can change `currentLine` to `currentLine.TrimStart()`.

Comment: That is interesting. How would search for multiple keywords then? Besides Date? Like I want to parse out several keywords, like Date, Serial, etc..

Comment: @KalaJ: You would have `if...else if...else if`, one for each keyword you want to parse.

Comment: That's what I thought but nothing is being printed out for some reason. It only works for one term

Comment: For some strange reason, the results are blank with StartsWith but works with IndexOf (However I do not get specific results).

Comment: You originally had a ':' like "Date:", now your edit shows no colon "Date".  Make sure you carefully match your `if` statements to what is actually in the file.

Comment: Yup, I did but it still doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you know that the file header is always the same you should just read first four lines explicitly. Clean, simple and the overall performance will be also better.

```
public void DeserialStream(string filePath)
{
    using (var sr = new StreamReader(filePath))
    {
        // header
        var dateLine = sr.ReadLine();
        var expirationDateLine = sr.ReadLine();
        var lotLine = sr.ReadLine();
        var serialLine = sr.ReadLine();

        // skip next two lines
        sr.ReadLine();
        sr.ReadLine()

        // csv data
        string currentline;
        while ((currentline = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(currentline);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What if I don't know if the header is the same? Is there a way to do it without that assumption?

Comment: well i don't know the background where those files are coming from. but i would say that those files with different headers should be handled differently. or they are invalid fiels

Comment: Actually, assuming that is yes, the file headers are the same every time, how would I parse something out let's say if I know that file header, Date, is always on Line 16, for instance? What if I want to parse something out that like Items, that spans multiple lines? Can I specify that I want to parse it "Items" on lines 20-25?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Dictionary<string, string>`, the key is the term and the value is... the value. Then you can use `String.StartsWith` with `StringcComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase` to check whether or not the line starts with that term. You get the value by using string methods like `Substring` or `IndexOf`. I assume that you're looking for the value after the space:

```
var lines = File.ReadLines(filePath);
var tokenValues = new Dictionary<string,string>{ { "Date", null }, { "Lot", null }, { "Serial", null } };
foreach (string line in lines)
{ 
    string l = line.TrimStart();
    string startsWithToken = tokenValues.Keys
        .FirstOrDefault(t => l.TrimStart().StartsWith(t, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase));
    if(startsWithToken != null)
        tokenValues[startsWithToken] = l.Substring(l.IndexOf(' ') + 1).Trim();
}
```

Comment: How do I check to see if the Dictionary is being populated with the correct strings? Console.WriteLine(tokenValues["Date"]); ?

Comment: You can either use ContainsKey or TryGetValue.

Comment: For some strange reason, StartsWith returns null for me. I'm not sure why.

Comment: StartsWith returns a bool which indicates whether or not the string started with the given sub-string.

Comment: I mean to say, if I run something like this: if (line.StartsWith("Date", StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) == true)
                //    {
                //        Console.WriteLine(line);

                //    }, nothing is outputted to line.

Comment: Can you show a sample line where you expect that it'll be outputted? Have you used TrimStart() first as shown in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

I would use regular expressions to get the lines you want. With them you can easily specify the format your expecting. Besides, I guess you'll want to extract some values from the lines later. With regular expressions you can get the values by using grouping constructs.

For the date example, one possible regex would be something like

`string dateRegex = @"Date: \d\d/\d\d/\d\d\d\d"`

To get the date value out, using grouping constructs,

`string dateRegex = @"Date: (?<day>\d\d)/(?<month>\d\d)/(?<year>\d\d\d\d)"`

The values would then be obtained from the parsed expression's groups by keys "date", "month" and "year".